# Progress Bar tied to a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I made this (for fun and education, I know it's not the most efficient)

https://codepen.io/paschos/pen/xxGXMQb

JS code I need help with

```
class App extends React.Component {

validate () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById("documentName").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    var type = document.getElementById("documentType");
    var typeChosen = type.options[type.selectedIndex].value;
    var category = document.getElementById("category");
    var categoryChosen = category.options[category.selectedIndex].value;

    if (name.length < 2 || name.length > 32) {
        alert("Invalid name length.");
    }
    else if (typeChosen === "" || categoryChosen === "") {
        alert("Please select a value from the dropdown list.");
    }
    else if (email.length > 128) {
        alert("Email exceedes character length.")
    }
    else if (re.test(email) === false) {
        alert("Invalid email adress.");
    }

}
getValue () {
    return "";
}

fillBar () {
    return (<progress max="100" value = {this.getValue()} id="progress">
            </progress>);
}

  render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit = {this.validate}>
         <div className = "form-progress-bar">
         {this.fillBar()}
        </div>
        <label htmlFor="documentName">Input the document name:</label>
        <br />
          <input id = "documentName"
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Document Name" 
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="documentType">Select document type:</label>
        <br />
        <select className = "dropdown" id = "documentType">
        <option defaultValue = ""> </option>
        <option value = "Plain" label = "Plain" />
        <option value = "PDF" label = "PDF" />
        </select> 
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="category">Select document category:</label>
        <br />
        <select className = "dropdown" id = "category">
        <option defaultValue >  </option>
        <option value = "Audit" label = "Audit" />
        <option value = "Application" label="Application" />
        <option value = "Other" label = "Other" />
        </select>
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="email">Input your email adress:</label>
        <br />
        <input id = "email"
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Email" 
        />
        <br />
        <button id = "button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

What I am stuck on is how to add 25 to the progress value each time a field of the form is being filled.

Code pen contains html and css code as well

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Can't help you on this one but +1 for the use of the html element `progress` instead of div like everyone else would probably do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a change handler and set your state with whether the field was filled or not. Then in the get value function, you would sum up all the truthy values in the state.

Example:

```
state = {
    (each field)
    emailFilled: false,
}

handleChange = (stateKey) => (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        [stateKey]: Boolean(value),
    });
}

getValue = () => {
    let value = 0;
    if(this.state.emailFilled) {
        value += 0.25;
    }
}

...
render(){
    ...
    <input id="email"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        onChange={this.handleChange('emailFilled')}
    />
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wrote it like this

    `getValue = () => {
        let value = 0;
        if(this.state.emailFilled || this.state.nameFilled || this.state.typeFilled || this.state.categoryFilled) {
            value += 25;
    }
        value = value.toString();

        return value;
}`

but it only adds 25 once :/

Comment: You have to check for each field separately. Otherwise you will only add 25 once regardless of how many fields you fill. If you do 4 ifs, then it will add it 4 times. (or better yet, a map over your state! [only if all the values in your state should be part of the progress bar])

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks pal! Your answer was super helpful